# iOS Client: "Caching" Server-side data to persistent storage

Tags: iphone, ios, json, core-data, architecture

I'm building an iOS client app to interface with an existing backend architecture. To reduce latency, API calls and payloads, it'd be nice to "cache" model data client-side for faster indexing and then make updates to both client/server sides accordingly as needed.

The current theoretical stack would look something like this:

```
Server Side >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Client Side
-----------------------------------------
PHP >> JSON >> CORE DATA >> UIKit Objects
```

***NOTE:** It's also worth noting that the iOS client, while itself adhering to MVC internally would in essence be a "View" in a larger MVC client-server architecture. Thus, just like one updates the model after a user action or updates the view after a model change, the server would need to sync with a client change and the client would need to sync with a server-side change.*

**Some Context:**

A. Many diverse data structures may be coming over the pipe and would have to be constructed into `UIViews` dynamically. A schema will likely have to be defined (I'm not sure if there's a "best way" to adhere to a `JSON` schema client-side other than remembering what the acceptable object structures are). I've realized the need to separate model data pertaining to the creation of custom views ("View" Models) from model data of what will be presented in those views ("Regular" Models).

B. End-users should be able to immediately **CRUD** (create, read, update, destroy) most data presented in these views (but not CRUD the views themselves). They may later need to view this in a web interface or other context.

C. RestKit looks like a good candidate for getting from the API to JSON to `COREDATA`. I need to find out if it structurally supports callbacks when client model copies need to be pushed to the server. Perhaps the best way is noting in the client model when a change has occurred and notifying whatever RestKit-based HTTP manager to pass it along to the server.

**Ultimate Question:**
Can anyone speak to best practices, pitfalls, tips, and frameworks with this type of architecture? (Particularly when it comes to performance and the distribution of work between client and server, but general advice is also much appreciated.)

Answer (score 1):

I've done some work around this, hopefully I can provide some insight.

In regards to A) Yes if you're planning to use CoreData (or RestKit) you'll need to know you schema up front.  You'll have no way to map dynamic objects otherwise unless you have some generic object type where you're just stashing the JSON string or something, but this doesn't sound like what you're trying to do since you mention users editing those objects.

B) RestKit will handle pushing to the server for you, but you'll still want some control over this I imagine.  We handled it by always saving locally first then pushing up to the server on a successful save.  This also enabled us to work when there's no network.  You'll just have to handle the edge cases of what happens when the server rejects the update / create / delete your user is performing.

C) RestKit will likely get you 80% of the way there, as it did for us.  Just having something to understand REST endpoints and object mapping, and abstracting the HTTP requests was a huge help.  In terms of the system understanding changes, we kept a flag on managed objects as to whether the object needed a sync or not.  We could fetch based on those flags and push the server up.

One thing with RestKit is that you can have other attributes in your CoreData model that aren't necessarily a part of the JSON schema, but you might need within your app.  For instance I already mentioned the flag for knowing whether an object needed sync.  We also kept pre-computed fields that we used to search on and some other random pieces of information for determining the order of objects to push up to the server (dependencies).

Hope this helps.  If you have more specific questions I might have more answers.